# Change src value depending on window aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, aspect-ratio, landscape-portrait

I'm new to Javascript. I've been trying to figure this out but now I'm stuck...

I have a background slider that doesn't keep its original aspect depending on the window size. To avoid too much distortion, for example on the Ipad in portrait mode. I thought I'd use another image source for my slider when the height of the window is greater than its width.
This is what i've got so far:

```
if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
document.getElementById('threesixty').attr('dataPath','path/to/imagesIpad{index}.jpg');  
 } 
else {  
 $('.threesixty').attr('data-path','path/to/images{index}.jpg'); }
```

and here's what's in the html

```
 <div class="threesixty" data-path="path/to/images{index}.jpg" data-count="72">
```

but this doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

First, 
 `document.getElementById('threesixty')` returns a dom object not a jquery object, you can't use `.attr()` method.

Second, why in `if` it's an id selector but in `else` it's a class selector `$('.threesixty')`???

Third, why in if it's attr `dataPath` but in `else` it's attr `data-path` ???

Please check your code